# How do I connect to multiple keyspaces using one Cassandra Client object?

Tags: node.js, database, cassandra, client, datastax-node-driver

I was using such a following code to connect to only 1 keyspace:

This is `/config/db.ts:

```
import cassandra from "cassandra-driver";

class Cpool {
static _pool : cassandra.Client;

static connect(options : any){
  this._pool = new cassandra.Client(options);
}


  static execute(query: string, params?: cassandra.ArrayOrObject | undefined, options?: cassandra.QueryOptions | undefined)
  {
    return this._pool.execute(query, params, options);
  }
}


export { Cpool };
```

And the below code is the `index.ts`:

```
  const default_options = {
    contactPoints: [process.env.CONTACT_POINTS],
    localDataCenter: process.env.LOCAL_DATA_CENTER,
    keyspace: process.env.KEYSPACE,
  };

  try {
    await Cpool.connect(default_options);
    console.log("Connected to Cassandra");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

Now I want to have 2 or more keyspaces but don't know should I create a new client in order to each of them or I can use only 1 client to connect to multiple keyspaces? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it's not necessary to specify `keyspace` property while generating a Cassandra client and connect it to the Cassandra Database, so I changed:

```
  const default_options = {
    contactPoints: [process.env.CONTACT_POINTS],
    localDataCenter: process.env.LOCAL_DATA_CENTER,
    keyspace: process.env.KEYSPACE,
  };
```

To:

```
  const default_options = {
    contactPoints: [process.env.CONTACT_POINTS],
    localDataCenter: process.env.LOCAL_DATA_CENTER,
  };
```

And I specified `keyspaces` inside my queries instead, like `INSERT INTO keyspace1.table_name ...` in place of `INSERT INTO table_name ....`

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple keyspaces in your database, you will need to fully qualify the tables in your query by explicitly specifying the keyspace name. For example:

```
query = "SELECT ... FROM keyspace_name.table_name WHERE ..."
```

or:

```
query = "INSERT INTO keyspace_name.table_name ... VALUES ..."
```

For best practice, only use one `Client` instance and reuse it for the life of your application. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you but what can I do with `const default_options = {
    contactPoints: [process.env.CONTACT_POINTS],
    localDataCenter: process.env.LOCAL_DATA_CENTER,
    keyspace: process.env.KEYSPACE,
  };` When I should specify the keyspace while creating a client.

Comment: I use `default_options` to create a `client` like `await Cpool.connect(default_options);` and inside the `defailt_options` I am specifying the keyspace. How can I specify multiple keyspaces there?

Comment: You don't specify multiple keyspaces when you create the `Client` object -- you specify the keyspace with the table in your queries. Cheers!