# updating all Cassandra tables starting with a specific name

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1, cassandra-cli

I am trying to alter my cassandra tables starting with a specific name.
My table starts with sample_1,sample_2,sample_13567,sample_adgf and so on...
The table names are random but starting with same prefix.

I want to add a new column to all these tables.
Can some one suggest me the update query using the regex for table names.

Comment: I dont have an answer for you but I have to tell you that having 13,500 tables, let alone more than a few hundred will eventually cause you pain in the form of JVM heap pressure. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux You can this in two step :

First Generate all alter command into a file like below :

```
for i in {1..13567}; do echo "ALTER TABLE sample_$i ADD test text;"; done > alter.cql
```

The above command will create alter command to add `test text` column for table `sample_1` to `sample_13567` and store into a file `alter.cql`

Now you can just load the cql file into cqlsh like below :

```
cqlsh 127.0.0.1 -u cassandra -p cassandra -k ashraful_test -f alter.cql
```

Here

```
-u username
-p password
-k keyspace_name
-f file name to load
```

By the way having too much table is not a good idea.
Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/33389204/2320144

Comment: Hi the table names are not sequential they are random but starting with same prefix.For example some tables can have sample_rt4f and sample_123r .I am trying to do from Dev Centre(cassandra ide like sql studio).I cannot do via linux as I dont have permissions to server.